# Knockout.js rendering datetime 12/31/1969

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Within a knockout VM I am trying to inject a date time into a property. The function generates the correct date but when it is rendered out in the UI I get a 12-31-1969 7pm date. 
This items is not being serialized and is being generated on the fly. Can someone help me understand why this is being generated and how to correct it. I have seen a number of articles on where this appears in php code but nothing specific to knockout. There was one article on SO that references the dateTimePicker but I did not immediately see a similarity between the OP's issue or mine.

Within my js file

```
function returnDateFormat() {

    var d = new Date();

    date = d.getDate();
    date = date < 10 ? "0" + date : date;

    mon = d.getMonth() + 1;
    mon = mon < 10 ? "0" + mon : mon;

    year = d.getFullYear();

    hours = d.getHours();

    min = d.getMinutes();

    sec = d.getSeconds();

    return (mon + "/" + date + "/" + year + " " + hours + ":" + min + ":" + sec);
}
```

Where the function is referenced in my ajax call on success. Basically I am trying to just update the VM to show the date when the event occured. This gets loaded and is bound in the UI when the page initializes so I know on the next load the correct value gets pulled from the DB and populates. I just didn't want to return the entire dateset back from call if I didn't have to.

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "warehouse/" + command,
       data: "{ productId:'" + product.ProductId() + "', newname: '" + newname + "' }",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (msg) {
       if (msg.Key == true) {
         DisplaySuccess("Update Complete.", "The product has been successfully updated.");
          //update product name in VM
          product.Name(newname);
          product.DateLastModified(returnDateFormat());
        }
        else {
        //Display error message if ajax msg fails
          DisplayError("Error Renaming Product ", msg.Value);
        }

       }, error: function (err) {
        DisplayError("Error Renaming Product", "The server returned an error code. Code: " + err.status);
     }
   });
```

then in the cshtml file I have the date modifed element bound to a div element

```
 <div title="Product Last Modified" class="productDetailItem scalableText productModified" data-bind="text: FormatDate(DateLastModified())"></div>
```

Update: On further investigation the original date is being passed in as a Json serialized string this is what the cshtml function call to FormatDate addresses. It parses and formats the Json string. I didn't realize this at the time as I had not written this portion of the mapping.

The reason it was breaking was I passing in a formatted date time and not a Json serialized string which the function expected. To correct this I plan to generate client side a date time and then serialize it, pass it to the function and this should correct the issue.  I will post a working solution soon.
 I would welcome other suggestions.
-cheers

Comment: What does that "FormatDate" function do?  It looks like you go to the trouble of formatting the timestamp in your "returnDateFormat", and then your binding wants to do it all over again.

Comment: What does the function FormatDate do in your databinding?

Comment: @Pointy I think I found the problem the FormatDate actually handles the Json serialized date (aka parses and formats) that is returned from the ajax call. That is what is causing the current problem with the date rendering.  Looks like I need to figure out how instead of injecting a standard date instead generate and serialize in Json a date time

Comment: as a side thought, have you looked at moment.js for dealing with date/time http://momentjs.com/

Comment: @christiandev This looks promising I will certainly take a look at this library

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want to do this instead:

```
<div title="Product Last Modified" class="productDetailItem scalableText productModified" data-bind="text: DateLastModified"></div>
```

DateLastModified is already formatted so why format it again?  As a side note, I highly recommend looking into [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).  You can replace your entire 'returnDateFormat' function with:

```
product.DateLastModified(moment().format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss a"));
// "09/05/2013 11:22:40 am"
```

Comment: Thanks the issue I found is I have to deal with two return types, The first is the Json serialized string which is returned from the server. This is what the FormatDate() function handled. The returnDateFormat was a second function that passed in a formatted date as a result the two formats conflict. I think generating and serializing a json datetime client side and then inserting that should correct the issue.

Comment: Ah. My recommendation would still be to remove the FormatDate function out of your binding.  Let's assume you resolve this conflict within the FormatDate function and you still want to pass it the current date formatted from the returnDateFormat function.  In the ajax success function, I would do: `product.DateLastModified(FormatDate(returnDateFormat()));`  This doesn't seem like a good approach, but just wanted to demonstrate that you should remove this 'business logic' from the UI and just let KO display whatever value you give the observables.

Comment: Totally agree on removing the business logic from the UI. Good catch and good suggestion.